# Phase in NTSC and TMS9918

Tags: video, ntsc

In the YIQ space (I am referring to this [wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YIQ)) colors with phases near 0 are close to red.

In the TMS9918 datasheet's table, however, in the expression of colors as A' and phase, blue colors have phase 354. (notice that the two greens have a reasonable phase).

[image]

I wondered whether Wikipedia's colors are off with the YIQ space, but they seem to be correct.

In fact let us take the following RGB to YIQ matrix (I found it [in this article](https://www.cs.unc.edu/~kmp/comp832-s08/readings/blinn-ntsc.pdf)):

$$ 
\left[ {\begin{array}{c} Y\\ I\\ Q\\ \end{array} } \right] =
\left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
  0.299 & 0.587 & 0.114 \\
  0.596 & -0.275 & -0.321 \\
  0.212 & -0.523 & 0.311 \\
\end{array} } \right]
\left[ {\begin{array}{c} R\\ G\\ B\\ \end{array} } \right]
$$

Its inverse is:

$$ 
\left[ {\begin{array}{c} R\\ G\\ B\\ \end{array} } \right] =
\left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
  1.0000 & 0.9557 & 0.6199 \\
  1.0000 & -0.2716 & -0.6469 \\
  1.0000 & -1.1082 & 1.7051 \\
\end{array} } \right]
\left[ {\begin{array}{c} Y\\ I\\ Q\\ \end{array} } \right]
$$

and by plugging in the colors for Y

$$I=A'cos(phase)$$
$$Q=A'sin(phase)$$

that correspond to the datasheet's table dark blue we get the RGB color:

$$\left[ {\begin{array}{ccc} 0.6657 & 0.3393 & 0.0159 \end{array} } \right]$$

or, in 0-255 range:

$$\left[ {\begin{array}{ccc} 170 & 87 & 4 \end{array} } \right]$$

which is a brownish red, and not blue:

[image: Sample of the resulting color]

(Color rendered with the [RGB Color Wheel](http://www.colorspire.com/rgb-color-wheel/)).

Comment: Dear Fabio, I've edited your question as best as I could, but please review it as I may have added an error or two. In particular, I didn't understand the part in which the multiplication by Y occur. How should the equations for I and Q be? Thanks!

Comment: thank you very much for your wonderful editing. I modified the sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table you provided in the question shows the phase angle with respect to Q axis. You are calculating with respect to I axis. Hence the difference.

So changing the equations to \$Q=A'cos(phase)\$ and \$ I=A'sin(phase)\$ will produce dark blue, the correct color.

Comment: thank you. I still needed to add 33 degrees to make the yellow (phase 173) be yellow, but rotation of the axis did the trick.